# HAML nesting error on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, nested

I just starting using HAML and I am not sure how to fix a nesting problem.
can someone shed some light please.
I am getting ""Illegal nesting: nesting within a tag that already has content is illegal."" for the last line

```
****_list.html.haml****
= render partial: 'admin/delayed_jobs/list_header'
-@jobs.each do |job|
  =link_to job.id do
    =render({:partial => 'admin/delayed_jobs/list_row', locals: {job:job}})

****Controller****

class Admin::DelayedJobsController < Admin::BaseController
  load_and_authorize_resource :delayed_job, class: Delayed::Job

  layout "admin"


def index
  @toggle_stats_job = Delayed::Job.where(queue: 'stats').first
  @jobs = Delayed::Job.where("COALESCE(delayed_jobs.queue, '') != 'stats'").order(:run_at)
 end

def show    
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render(json: {payload: @delayed_job.handler}.to_json) }
    format.html { redirect_to admin_delayed_jobs_path }
  end
end

def destroy
  @job = Delayed::Job.find(params[:id])
  @job.destroy
  redirect_to admin_delayed_jobs_path
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, there is only single id `= link_to job.id do`, you can't loop that

```
= render partial: 'admin/delayed_jobs/list_header'
- @jobs.each do |job|
   = link_to job.id, job
   = render :partial => "admin/delayed_jobs/list_row", :locals => {:job => job}
```

Comment: I am still getting 
Illegal nesting: nesting within a tag that already has content is illegal.

Comment: Well that solved the nesting problem!! but gave me a new one ""undefined method `delayed_backend_active_record_job_path' for ""

Comment: show me your controller method where you have defined `Delayed::Job.enqueue`